# Broken google drive permission API for update/patch

Tags: google-drive-api

Google drive permission API for update/patch don't work as expected. The update/patch gets added as a new permission instead of updating the existing one. The documentation clearly says it should update existing permission. Is anyone else seeing the same issue? Appreciate any help.

Before patch list output::

```
{
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "etag": "\"7_qGCxxuhPBUXrfn7_2ZO3McVUQ/LsilxThzTS3OBJ1rbF7YEIEg1oo\"",
  "id": "08822980745812584915i",
  "selfLink": "...",
  "emailAddress": "XXXXXX@yahoo.com",
  "domain": "yahoo.com",
  "role": "writer",
  "type": "user"
}
```

Patch request/response::

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1SUds1Cjnr8xKzekkWqx9ECsUZXbEOLUGKFKb4y_LUwo/permissions/08822980745812584915i?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_WduvpsYzvK9o_skeJ-LkpJgkWeW3tFMxEN4gBv1pVU4tEM-ClpfYLXp65GqnodScrj-L5qaDA
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
  "role": "reader"
}

{
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "etag": "\"7_qGCxxuhPBUXrfn7_2ZO3McVUQ/lEg2fxSB9Duh6yZZqNOBgWKW5JY\"",
  "id": "08822980745812584915i",
  "selfLink": "...",
  "emailAddress": "XXXXXX@yahoo.com",
  "domain": "yahoo.com",
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user"
}
```

List output after patch::

```
{
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "etag": "\"7_qGCxxuhPBUXrfn7_2ZO3McVUQ/ohtKstgNWK6Bocb03Cur-LaeY2g\"",
  "id": "00371221158164555836",
  "selfLink": "...",
  "name": "",
  "domain": "",
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user"
},
{
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "etag": "\"7_qGCxxuhPBUXrfn7_2ZO3McVUQ/LsilxThzTS3OBJ1rbF7YEIEg1oo\"",
  "id": "08822980745812584915i",
  "selfLink": "...",
  "emailAddress": "XXXXXX@yahoo.com",
  "domain": "yahoo.com",
  "role": "writer",
  "type": "user"
}
```

As you can see, it creates a new permission with domain and name fields as blank. The permission id is same in the list output and patch request

Comment: What is the existing permission, and what update are you sending?

Comment: The existing role on the permission is writer and try changing it to reader. I see the same issue when using 'try now' option on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/patch. Updated issue with relevant information

Comment: Confused by your patch request there.. are you doing more than just setting the id and role = reader?

Comment: Hi Cheryl, just fixed the indentation to make it readable. In the request body, I am just passing the role as reader

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Is it possible you are passing in the wrong permission id?  Make sure that it matches between the list response and the patch request.

Original list response:

...

```
 {

   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "etag": "<...>",
   "id": "01850103618484623959",
   "selfLink": <...>,
   "name": "Bob Dole",
   "domain": "",
   "role": "writer",
   "type": "user"
  }
```

...

Patch request:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B2bhoijNAMV2UU9iMkpGbWktckxxSS1ra1lkQ0lTN052bWFn/permissions/01850103618484623959?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_VTwYJGkJw1SDuRf3S-n19-yZggimhaZLqmbOPlWjLiRCCEIknswZhccWgaKMIgf62IC6TcJK0
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "role": "reader"
}
```

New list response:

...

```
   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "etag": "<...>",
   "id": "01850103618484623959",
   "selfLink":<...>,
   "name": "Bob Dole",
   "domain": "",
   "role": "reader",
   "type": "user"
  }
```

...

Comment: Hi Cheryl, I tried again and made sure permission id is right. I have updated ticket with appropriate output of list and patch commands. See the same issue. Appreciate your help.